# Problems solving/plotting a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying the following:

```
Plot[DSolve[{1220*x''[t] + 1000*x'[t] + 35600 x[t] + 4500*x[t]^3 + 
     2135 == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -5}, x, t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I am just getting the same input if I just try:

```
DSolve[{1220*x''[t] + 1000*x'[t] + 35600 x[t] + 4500*x[t]^3 + 
     2135 == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -5}, x, t]
```

I have used Mathematica to solve these kinds of equations before but I'm drawing a blank here. It's just the good ol' mass-spring-damper system.

Comment: If `DSolve` cannot solve the DE, which seems to be the case, you can use `NDSolve` to get a solution that you can plot.  Would that be okay, or do you need the symbolic solution?

Comment: NDSolve gives me:   x[t] -> Interpolating function. I just really need to plot it. A symbolic solution would be nice, but not necessary.

Comment: Yep.  The documentation shows examples of plotting the result.  Does that work?

Comment: Mmmm.. I can't seem to get it to work. I'll fiddle with it some more. I have never seen said output. Mathematica rookie :)

Comment: `It's just the good ol' mass-spring-damper system.` Well, it is a special spring you have and not the good old one. You have non-linear spring, so this makes it hard to find closed form solution. Are you saying Mathematica solved this analytically before?

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}]`, where `sol = NDSolve[....` and you can change `0` and `1` to your limits for `t`.

Comment: "Are you saying Mathematica solved this analytically before?" No, not this one in particular. This is for a landing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolveValue.html):

```
ClearAll[xfunc1, x, t]
xfunc1 = NDSolveValue[{1220*x''[t] + 1000*x'[t] + 35600 x[t] + 
      4500*x[t]^3 + 2135 == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -5}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[xfunc1[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Or use `NDSolve` and `ReplaceAll` to get the solution function:

```
ClearAll[xfunc2, x, t]
xfunc2 =  x /. NDSolve[{1220*x''[t] + 1000*x'[t] + 35600 x[t] + 
         4500*x[t]^3 + 2135 == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -5}, x, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];

Plot[xfunc2[t], {t, 0, 10}]
(* same picture *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NDSolve

```
sol = NDSolve[{1220*x''[t] + 1000*x'[t] + 35600 x[t] + 4500*x[t]^3 + 2135 == 0,
               x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -5}, x, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]